# Sensors Android Sample Rate

Tags: android, android-sensors

I'm trying to get the sensors working with a stable sensor rate.
Example of one of the Sensor Events!

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event)
{
    SensorManager.getRotationMatrixFromVector(rotation, event.values);
    SensorManager.getOrientation(rotation, orientation);
    orientation[0]=(float)Math.toDegrees(orientation[0]);
    orientation[1]=(float)Math.toDegrees(orientation[1]);
    orientation[2]=(float)Math.toDegrees(orientation[2]);

    azimuth.setText(String.valueOf(orientation[0]));
    pitch.setText(String.valueOf(orientation[1]));
    roll.setText(String.valueOf(orientation[2]));

    elapsedTime = (System.currentTimeMillis() /1000.0) - startTime ;
    sampleRate = 1 / (elapsedTime - oldElapsedTime);
    sampleRateText.setText(String.valueOf(sampleRate));

    list.add(String.valueOf(elapsedTime).replace(".", ",") + ";");
    list.add(String.valueOf(orientation[0]).replace(".", ",") + ";");
    list.add(String.valueOf(orientation[1]).replace(".", ",") + ";");
    list.add(String.valueOf(orientation[2]).replace(".", ",") + ";");

    oldElapsedTime = elapsedTime;
}
```

Excel graph SensorRate [RotationVector](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html#TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR):
[image]

Excel graph SensorRate [Accelero](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html#TYPE_ACCELEROMETER):
[image]

As you can see the Accelero sensor has a much worser sensor rate.
I know that an OS as Android does many things at once a perfect stable sensor rate is impossible. 
So my question is if someone has experienced the same and what did you do?

Sincerely
Brecht